# CSS Dot Leaders With Textured Background

Tags: css, list

How do I add CSS dot leaders over a textured background?

I'm familiar with adding dot leaders between elements, but I cannot find a method that lets me add them when the text is over a textured background.

However, because the menu is dynamic, the elements won't have a permanent location. Since they aren't permanant, I cannot use a background image to make my dots work.

Comment: I don't know what you want or what your problem is, but here are some examples: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders

Comment: A nice example http://stackoverflow.com/a/29356813/383904

Answer (score 4):

You can use floats and the behavior of `display:block;overflow:hidden`.

If the floats (left and right) are placed before the block with the style above, they would make this block the width equal to the width of the parent minus their width.

So, here is the [live example at dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/4161142) — you can achieve it with almost any markup and use any style (background instead of dotted border) on the leader element.

Comment: +1, this is a really clean and, in my opinion, semantic way to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, the semantic way to do dl's is to wrap each pair into the list tag.

Answer (score 2):

I did small experiment:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/5QYEz/**

HTML

```
<ul class="leaders">
    <li>
        <span class="description">Pierwszy punkt</span>
        <span class="destination">2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="description">Drugi element listy</span>
        <span class="destination">5</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.leaders {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -0.3em;
}

ul.leaders li {
    height: 1.2em;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}

ul.leaders .description,
ul.leaders .destination {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.3em 0 -0.3em 0;
    background: #fff;
}

ul.leaders .description {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
}

ul.leaders .destination {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The OP was asking for help with doing this with a textured background, simply masking the elements with a background color will NOT work with what the OP was wanting. I'm running into the same issue too. The suggestion on w3.org does not satisfy this requirement either. :/