# Placing a fluid-width pseudo-element between two floated elements

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, pseudo-element

**EDIT**: figured it out - see the answer below for solution.

**Background**: I have two elements, an `h1` and a `span`. I'm trying to place the `h1` "Title" element on the left of the container element and the `span` "category" element on the right of the container, which I've done with `float: left` and `:right`.

**Problem**: I'd like a dotted line to appear between the `h1` and `span` elements. If possible, I'd like to use a pseudo-element for this since it's purely aesthetic, so I'm trying to get the `h1:after` pseduo-element to fill the remaining width of the container element between the `h1` and `span`.

[image]

I'm trying to keep my HTML as close to the following as possible:

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span class="category">Category</span>
</header>
```

My CSS so far - the `:after` pseudo-element is currently positioned beneath the `h1` element, as opposed to between the `h1` and `span`:

```
header {
  display: block;
  background: cyan;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  float: left; 
}
h1:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  content: " ";
}
span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after more research, I discovered that what I'm looking for is called a dot leader. While the W3C Working Draft has a section on them [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#leaders), they don't seem to be well-implemented yet. I found another approach on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605769/1592764). Using that answer, I revised my code as follows:

**HTML**:

```
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span>Category</span>
  </header>
```

**CSS**:

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 .4em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
span {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 .4em;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Dot Leader */
header:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the result: http://jsfiddle.net/dx48R/

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/FckuL/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span>title</span>
    <span class="category">category</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid;
}
span{
    line-height:50px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
span.category{
    float:right;
}
.container:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
        height:0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #4c5660;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the code, but I'll probably be using these elements against a background image, and placing a background color on the title and category to hide the full dotted line won't work - I'm trying to find a solution that allows the line to only span the width between the title and category.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way, sorry I don't know any other way with CSS

Comment: No problem, if you're interested I think I found another way; I've posted it below