# CSS responsive multiline list with dashed lines (name - - - price)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make a multi-line dot leader when the background is textured or you don't know the background. The W3C site provides a [good example](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html) when you know the background color, but that doesn't work for my needs. [Here is a SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957952/css-dot-leaders-with-textured-background) of a textured background that works really well, but the leaders disappear when the line breaks to a 2nd line. Unfortunately the two use a different method to achieve this effect, so I'm not sure the best way to combine the best of both worlds here...

Here's sorta what I'm thinking. Is it possible?

[image: example]

Comment: Your first example uses `li:before` to create the dot leader for one line items. You can use `li:after` to mimic the effect for the last line. Maybe with some clever conditions you can alternate between the two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something from the top of my mind:
<sub>(Honestly I don't know for any other better **and responsive** solution):</sub>

[image: CSS dashed list multiline leader]

***[jsBin demo (so you can resize and play with)](http://jsbin.com/jojoqu/2/edit)***

- Place 2 `span` (as table-cell) inside a `LI` set as `table`
- Trick the last span to `width: 1%;`
- Add the desired dashes or dots or even a background-image to the first  `span`'s `:after` pseudo element

```css
body{background:orange;}    /* No other backgrounds are used */

ul.leaders {
  padding:        0;
}
ul.leaders li {
  display:        table;
}
ul.leaders li span {
  display:        table-cell;
}
ul.leaders li span:first-child { /* TITLE */
  position:       relative;
  overflow:       hidden;       /* Don't go underneath the price */
}
ul.leaders li span:first-child:after { /* DASHES */
  content:        "";
  position:       absolute;
  bottom:         0.5em;        /* Set as you want */       
  margin-left:    0.5em;        /* Keep same for the next span's left padding */
  width:          100%;
  border-bottom:  1px dashed #000;
}
ul.leaders li span + span {     /* PRICE */
  text-align:     right;
  width:          1%;           /* Trick it */
  vertical-align: bottom;       /* Keep Price text bottom-aligned */
  padding-left:   0.5em;
  /* white-space: nowrap;       /* Uncomment if needed */
}
```

```html
<ul class=leaders>
  <li>
    <span>Salmon Ravioli</span>
    <span>7.95</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Pan seared Ahi with avocado, soy, ginger and lime</span>
    <span>8.95</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Almond Prawn Cocktail</span>
    <span>7.95</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Bruschetta</span>
    <span>45.25</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Margherita Pizza</span>
    <span>108.95</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In this case we will have problems with multiline labels.

Comment: @DmitrySikorsky done finally. The only *issue* is the use of `<br>`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, this looks pretty good. Any way of doing this without the nowrap?

Comment: @Jeff I'm trying to find a smart solution

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Looks amazing and works really well! Thanks so much :)