# HTML/CSS - Make dotted line fill the same on different items

Tags: html, css

I want to make a simple menu cart, for food, made like this:

Fish............10
Potatoe.........10
soup............20

Aligned perfectly, with dots, and same width etc.

But in simps, html, this doesn't apply - the width is different, i can't get them align perfectly, this is how it looks:

[image: description of screenshot]

How do i make it all equal, without editing font size, letter spacing etc?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us what have you done so far? :)

Comment: One of the simplest ways is to use table

Comment: Another solution would be to use [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) :-)

Comment: It duplicates a question which already has a very good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356534/css-responsive-multiline-list-with-dashed-lines-name-price/29356813

Answer (score 7):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align things:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}

li .dots {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fish<span class="dots"></span><span>10</span>
  </li>
  <li>Potato<span class="dots"></span><span>20</span>
  </li>
  <li>Soup<span class="dots"></span><span>10</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround to this would be to use a `monospaced font`. I would go for a more dynamic solution like the one proposed by [@ovokuro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5561605/ovokuro) and avoid counting characters, but anyway here is a demo of this approach:

```css
.monospaced {font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
  <li>Fish............10</li>
  <li>Potatoe.........10</li>
  <li>soup............20</li>
</ul>

<ul class="monospaced">
  <li>Fish............10</li>
  <li>Potatoe.........10</li>
  <li>soup............20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` to align the items properly:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Fish..........</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Potato........</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Soup..........</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```